# std::find and boost::make_indirect_iterator - compilation error

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl, visual-studio-2005

I have a problem. Why can't I compile this? What is wrong?

```
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

bool finder(std::list<SomeObject*>::const_iterator first, 
        std::list<SomeObject*>::const_iterator last, 
        const SomeObject& x) 
{
   return std::find(boost::make_indirect_iterator(first),
                    boost::make_indirect_iterator(last),
                    x) != boost::make_indirect_iterator(last); 
}
```

// This code is from answer to my previous post

I have errors like:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   8\VC\include\algorithm(40) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const
>   _Ty &,const std::complex<_Other> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'const SomeObject
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   8\VC\include\algorithm(40) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const
>   std::complex<_Other> &,const _Ty &)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'const std::complex<_Other> &' from 'SomeObject'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   8\VC\include\algorithm(40) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const
>   std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not
>   deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from
>   SomeObject

and several similar errors..

I have defined `operator==`:

```
bool operator==(const SomeObject& x, const SomeObject& y)
{
    return x.id1() == y.id1();
}
```

I use VS 2005.

How to fix it? What is wrong? Maybe it's VS2005 bug? Can You compile this?

Answer (score 1):

It means *advance(boost::make_indirect_iterator(first), some_int) can not be passed to operator == which accepts const SomeObject&. And this is strange.

One suggestion would be to keep bool operator== inside namespace std.

```
namespace std {
  bool operator==(const SomeObject& x, const SomeObject& y)
  {
    return x.id1() == y.id1();
  }
}
```

Comment: How should I define operator== ?

Comment: Can you try moving operator== into namespace std?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really works! But it's very strange for me... Does anyone know how to do that better? Nicest?

Comment: Compiler tried to find a match for comparision operator in std namespace and unfortunately a generic templatized version of comparision operator matched. Bang!!! About how to do it better, I would suggest you to pass comparision function as fourth argument to std::find.

Comment: I am sorry for my previous statement, though never used, but I had an impression that find take comparision function as optional fourth argument. Just ignore my comment. I would think of a cleaner way and post.

Comment: OK, I thought the same. BTW it's weird that std::find does not have fourth optional argument - predicate. Unfortunately, it's not added to C++11 standard neither. :( Thanks. You've helped me a lot. If you find better solution of, please write.

Comment: You can overload comparision operator inside your class SomeObject. class SomeObject { ... public: bool operator ==(const SomeObject &y) const { return id1() == y.id1(); } };